# How do I have multiple rand generators in one code?

Tags: c++, class, header, random-seed

I am writing a code to sort an array of random integers using four sorting methods bubble, selection, shell and quick sort.  I'm using the same code as a rand generator to create random integers which can be sorted by the sort functions. My issue is that when I run multiple sort methods at the same time; my rand generators create the same set of integers for the arrays. How do I fix this so I can have parallel rand generators in the same program? I cannot use c++11 array or STL vector.

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "AssortedSorter.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    AssortedSorter q, q2;
    int UserNumOfNumbers;
    int bchoice;

    cout << " We pick array size (0) or you pick array size (1): ";
    cin >> bchoice;

    while (bchoice == 0) {
        UserNumOfNumbers = 10000;

        int array[UserNumOfNumbers];
        srand(std::time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < UserNumOfNumbers; i++) {
            array[i] = (rand() %200002) + 1;
        }

        cout << "\nArray Elements ::" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < UserNumOfNumbers; i++) {
            // long b = array[i];
            q.quicksort(array, 0, UserNumOfNumbers);
            q.bubbleSort(array, UserNumOfNumbers);
            cout << " Number of Elements " << i + 1 << "::" << array[i] << endl;
           // q.quicksort(array, 0, UserNumOfNumbers);
        }
        //q.bubbleSort(array, UserNumOfNumbers);}

        // q.selectionSort(array, UserNumOfNumbers);}
        return 0;
    }

    while (bchoice == 1) {
        cout << "Enter a number between 10 and 20000: ";

        cin >> UserNumOfNumbers;
        while (UserNumOfNumbers < 10 || UserNumOfNumbers > 20000) {
            cout << "Invalid entry! Please enter a valid value: ";
            cin >> UserNumOfNumbers;

        }
        int array[UserNumOfNumbers];
        srand(std::time(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < UserNumOfNumbers; i++)
            array[i] = (rand() %200002) + 1;


        cout << "\nArray Elements ::" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < UserNumOfNumbers; i++) {
            q.bubbleSort(array, UserNumOfNumbers);
            cout << " Number of Elements " << i + 1 << "::" << array[i] <</*(rand() %200002) + 1 */endl;
        }

        int arra[UserNumOfNumbers];
        srand(std::time(NULL));
        for (int j = 0; j < UserNumOfNumbers; j++)
            arra[j] = (rand() %200002) + 1;

        cout << "\nArray Elements ::" << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < UserNumOfNumbers; j++) {
            q.quicksort(arra, 0, UserNumOfNumbers);
            cout << " Number of Elements " << j + 1 << "::" << arra[j] << endl;
        }
        /*int arran[UserNumOfNumbers];
        srand(std::time(0));
        for (int k = 0; k < UserNumOfNumbers; k++)
            arran[k] = (rand() %200002) + 1;

        cout << "\nArray Elements ::" << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < UserNumOfNumbers; k++) {
            q.selectionSort(arran, UserNumOfNumbers);
            cout << " Number of Elements " << k + 1 << "::" <<(rand() %200001) + 1  << endl;}*/
        break;
    }
    }
```

AssortedSorter.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AssortedSorter.h"

//long array;
using namespace std;


int AssortedSorter::partition(int array[], int start, int stop){
    int up = start, down = stop - 1, part = array[stop];
    long loopCountQ, swapCountQ;
    if (stop <= start)
        return start;
    while (true)
    {
        while (array[up] < part){
         /*   loopCountQ++;
            cout << " Loop Count++: " << loopCountQ << endl;*/
            up++;}



        while ((part < array[down]) && (up < down)){
           /* loopCountQ++;
            cout << " Loop Count--: " << loopCountQ << endl;*/
            down--;}
        if (up >= down)
            break;

        swap(array[up], array[down]);{
          /*  swapCountQ++;
            cout << " Swap Count: " << swapCountQ << endl;*/
            up++;
            down--;}
    }
    swap(array[up], array[stop]);{
     /*   swapCountQ++;
        cout << " Swap Count: " << swapCountQ << endl;*/
        return up;}
}
int AssortedSorter ::getquicksort() const {
    return *b;
}

void AssortedSorter :: quicksort(int a[], int start, int stop){
    int i, s = 0, stack[20001];
   // b = a;
    //long * array = (a);
    stack[s++] = start;
    stack[s++] = stop;
    while ( s > 0)
    {
        stop = stack[--s];
        start = stack[--s];
        if (start >= stop) continue;

         i = partition(a, start, stop);
        if
        (i - start > stop - i)
        {
            stack[s++] = start; stack[s++] = i - 1;
            stack[s++] = i + 1; stack[s++] = stop;
        }
        else {
            stack[s++] = i + 1; stack[s++] = stop;
            stack[s++] = start; stack[s++] = i - 1;
        }
    }


}

void AssortedSorter:: bubbleSort(int array[], int size) {
    int maxElement;
    int index;
    //long loopcount = 0;

    for (maxElement = size - 1; maxElement > 0; maxElement--) {
        for (index = 0; index < maxElement; index++) {

            if (array[index] > array[index + 1]) {/*loopcount++;
                cout << " Loop count: " << loopcount << endl;*/
                swap(array[index], array[index + 1]);

            }
        }
    }
}

/*void AssortedSorter :: swap(int &a, int &b){
   /* long int swapcount = 0;
    {swapcount++;
        cout << "Swap count: " << swapcount << endl;}
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;

}*/

void AssortedSorter::selectionSort(int array[], int size)
{
    int minIndex, minValue;
    long int loopcountsel = 0;

    for (int start = 0; start < (size - 1); start++)
    {
        minIndex = start;
        minValue = array[start];

        for (int index = start + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if(array[index] < minValue)
            {
                loopcountsel++;
               // cout << "Loop count: " << loopcountsel << endl;

            }

            if(array[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }
        swap(array[minIndex], array[start]);
    }

}

void AssortedSorter :: swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

AssortedSorter.h

```
#ifndef SORTER_ASSORTEDSORTER_H
#define SORTER_ASSORTEDSORTER_H

class AssortedSorter {
public:


    void quicksort(int a[], int, int);
    int getquicksort() const;
    int partition(int [], int, int);

    void bubbleSort(int[], int);
    int getbubblesort() const;
    //void swap(int & , int &);
    int getswap() const;

    void selectionSort(int[], int);
    void swap(int &, int &);


private:
    int* b;
};

#endif //SORTER_ASSORTEDSORTER_H
```

Comment: Use [pseudorandom number generators from the `<random>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead of `rand()`.

Comment: call srand once at the start o your program. and VLAs are not part of c++